# Making an azure cloud project work on/off the cloud?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, wcf-data-services

What are the steps required to make a project developed for azure (also) deploy-able off the cloud, for example on a Windows Server computer? My project has 2 worker roles. One is basically a data-miner, and the other hosts a (self-hosted) WCF service. It uses the Azure Table Service, Queue and Blob Service. How would these elements translate off the cloud ? A SQL Database or maybe a NoSql approach? How would I add a level of abstraction to allow it to use whichever resource is actually available, without the need to modify the underlying implementation (ie the my DataServiceContext classes to remain mostly untouched)?

**EDIT 1:**

Worker Role <=> Windows Service

Azure Table Service <=> EntityFramework + WCF Data Service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had worked on a project which need to be deployed on both cloud and local, with the same code base. Maybe I can share some thoughts from my side.

There are many aspects we need to care about when design, mainly focus on the different environment between cloud and local and build some virtulization layer in our system. So that we can switch thruogh the configuration.

1. File system: We had had a virtual file operation interface which contains the methods for file saving, deleting and getting. And then we had two implementation classes for local and blob.
2. Database: This can be done easily through a simple SQL helper class supporting SQL Server and SQL Azure. Just need to change the connection string. But when using SQL Server we also follow the restrictions of SQL Azure such as no cross database query.
3. Configuration: We moved some configuration to database with cache enabled from web.config, especially for those configuration elements might be changed at runtime. This is becuase when deploying on the cloud, we cannot change web.config unless push a new package.
4. Hosting: Since our project is a WCF service, we had created several hosting projects for the underlying service implementation. Some of them for local deployment such as Windows Service hosting, Console App hosting and IIS hosting. We also have a web role and wroker role that can be used to host our service on the cloud. The hosting projects were very simple, and all of them are using the same service implementation classes.
5. Log: We leveraged our file system layer so that the log can be saved in local file (local deploy) or table service (cloud deploy).
6. Cache: We learned the code from ServiceStack and built a cache interface and some implementations for Windows Server AppFabric Cache and Windows Azure Shared Cahce. It can be switched thruogh configuration. And for the next version we are going to implement antoher implementation class for Cloud Service Cache.
7. Stateless: We ensured our application, especially the service implementation is stateless. This is very important not only for cloud deployment but local as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Problem is I didn't use SqlAzure, I used the Table Service. So I'm trying to use EntityFramework code first approach + WCF Data Services to replace Azure Table Service. Is that a good aproach ?

Comment: Did you mean you want to use EntityFramework to work with Table Service? I don't think EF provides this feature so you might need to deep customize it.

Comment: No, use EntityFramework and WCF Data Services to act like a Windows Azure Table Service "look-a-like". Since TableDataContext derives from DataServiceContext, I think that might be a good approach. What do you think?

Comment: I think I got your point. Currently you have a cloud project that is using table service, and you want to use SQL Server + EF + WCF Data Service to somehow simulate the table service so that in your business layer you can use each of them as you need. I've never tried but I think it's possible, as you said table service SDK came from WCF Data Service binaries. But if you are using WCF Data Service you have to communicate with your database through WCF, which might introduce performance issue. How about create an abstract layer in front of your table service and EF.

Comment: How would I do that ? Could I point the TableServiceContext to use an SQL database ? (In the meantime I'm having some unnecessary delays with nuget and source control, ugh)

Comment: Ok so I didn't use WCF DS anymore (something went terribly wrong there). Instead I made an interface ITableAccess { get;} and the implementation: IQueryable<Type>get {return _context.SomeDbset.AsQueryable();}. That sounds about right. I think.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you are not going to be able to pull it off without quite a lot of rework. Although your web/worker roles may be easier to move, your big problem is the use of Azure storage. While you could (or could have) abstracted your storage and injected in whatever the appropriate storage is, it is likely that you have (whether explicitly or not) made design considerations that are Azure storage specific. This means that what you have implemented may work well on Azure, but not well on premise. For example, there are a lot of features of blob storage, such as page blobs or redundancy, that you made use of, that will not be available with traditional disk-based storage.

A while back I sent Scott Gu an email specifically asking about what do with the lack of an on premise storage product with API compatibility with Azure storage. He replied by saying that API compatibility is something that they are working on and would show up later in the year (last year 2012). I assume that referred to Azure websites (and other IaaS) running on premise - which they announced in preview last year. As far as storage and compute, there is nothing yet.

I recommend that you avoid trying to build your application for both Azure and on premise from the same code and infrastructure base. Since you have started on Azure, question the need for on premise and try and uncover the underlying need. Is it security fears? Sense of ownership? Cost? Perhaps you can understand what is really being asked for and address those concerns within your Azure application. Maybe a bit of selling the benefits of running on Azure will be easier than rewriting. After all, there are not many use cases where an application **absolutely has to** run on premise - otherwise we wouldn't be dong this cloud thing at all.

Comment: A very interesting answer! The use of Azure Storage was also my main concern. The 'problem' I'm trying to 'solve' is in-case we ever need to move away from Azure for any reason (be it cost or I don't know, "The Cloud is the Devil") , how this move could be done in an efficient and straight-forward way, w/o the need to rewrite too much, since the clients have already been implemented for Windows8, iOS and Android. Since there are a ton of examples on how to port existing apps to the cloud, I was hoping to get an idea on what such an existing app might look like, to be able to do the opposite.

Comment: To address the (potential) cost issue I've made a (slim) client farm to stress test the service, and see what kinds of costs we might incur in the course of a month. I've also added gzip compression on the service. The goal is to not pass (by too much) our BizSpark subscription. Other than costing a ridiculous amount for the (insane) number of potential customers I'm planning to stress with, I don't see any reason why the app should run on premise... But hey...